# How do you combine a picklist and input field in visualforce?

Tags: visualforce

I'm making a vf page that will display some values to user in a `selectList`. I'm also giving the user the option to enter their own details if they don't wish to choose anything in the list.

I've looked around but can't find anything on the net except something on sControls that seems unsupported now.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely an argument for only allowing values from the list in a picklist field i.e. making one of the options "Other" and having a separate text field where users can enter free text.

However, you can configure a picklist to allow other values. Just make sure that "Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set" is unchecked in the field settings.

As for how to present that to the user, I tend to use a Javascript UI library like https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Comment: I'm not getting the values from an sObject. I'm constructing the picklist in my controller. I suppose "picklist" isn't the right term to use. My bad.

Comment: OK, but if you are using a selectList tag in Visualforce, that will get rendered as a HTML select element. At which point, you can override it using selectize or whatever other library you like. Those libraries hide the original input element, but still update that element on changes, so the results will end up back in your VF controller.